# how to make currentPage dynamic on pageInfo gatsby graphql?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, graphql, gatsby

good day. Im using gatsby in the front and strapi as backend. Im trying to make a media gallery with simple pagination to select images for a custom component.

I get the images and using this query

```
query MyQuery($currentPage: Int!) {
  allStrapiMedia(limit: 20,currentPage:$currentPage ) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      itemCount
      hasNextPage
      pageCount
      currentPage
      perPage
      totalCount
      hasPreviousPage
    }
  }
}
```

but i get this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"currentPage\" on field \"Query.allStrapiMedia\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 28
        }
      ],
      "stack": [
        "GraphQLError: Unknown argument \"currentPage\" on field \"Query.allStrapiMedia\".",
        "    at Object.Argument (/Users/alexeigarban/Documents/projects/platformable/platformablecodegenerator copy/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/KnownArgumentNamesRule.js:46:29)",
        "    at Object.enter (/Users/alexeigarban/Documents/projects/platformable/platformablecodegenerator copy/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:323:29)",
        "    at Object.enter (/Users/alexeigarban/Documents/projects/platformable/platformablecodegenerator copy/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:370:25)",
        "    at visit (/Users/alexeigarban/Documents/projects/platformable/platformablecodegenerator copy/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)",
        "    at validate (/Users/alexeigarban/Documents/projects/platformable/platformablecodegenerator copy/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)",
        "    at /Users/alexeigarban/Documents/projects/platformable/platformablecodegenerator copy/node_modules/express-graphql/index.js:121:32",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "extensions": {}
}
```

if i  remove the currentPage var it works but im not able to go to currentPage:2 , ...+, that means that i only can see the first 20.

What am i missing?

thanks for your time

Comment: use playground to check args ... use `start: (currentPage - 1) * perPage` ?

Comment: thanks for your response, should i use that in here :allStrapiMedia(limit: 20,currentPage:$currentPage ): i dont have "start" just limit, skip and sort),

Comment: ....... try skip ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you are passing the required arguments from teh apollo client

ex.

```
this.queryArticles = this.apollo
      .watchQuery({
        query: ARTICLES_QUERY,
        variables: {
          start: start,
          limit: this.limit
        }
      })
      .valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result.data;
        this.articles = this.data.articles;
        this.loading = result.loading;
        this.errors = result.errors;
      });
  }
```

Ref: https://www.codinghub.net/article/pagination-integration-with-strapi-angular-and-graphql

2. While filtering pls use offset i.e, start index for the record index

articles(start:$start, limit:$limit, sort:"published_at:desc")

Ref: https://www.codinghub.net/article/pagination-integration-with-strapi-angular-and-graphql

Comment: thanks for your response, i dont see "start" just, limit, skip and sort)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not passing the `currentPage` value in a specific loop (maybe the edge cases, first or last), from your page creation to your templates. In addition, you are not using this value to filter the query in `allStrapiMedia`.

In your `gatsby-node.js` file, you should get the `currentPage` but this information is missing in the question.

Assuming a markdown approach:

```
const path = require("path")
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const queryResults = await graphql(`
    query allPages{
      allPages {
        nodes {
          id
          currentPage
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const productTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/product.js`)
  queryResults.data.allPages.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
      path: `/page/${node.id}`,
      component: pageTemplate,
      context: {
        currentPage: currentPage
      },
    })
  })
}
```

*Note: tweak it to adapt it to your Strapi environment but get the idea.*

The idea is to pass via context the currentPage value extracted from the GraphQL query for all cases, included the edge cases.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, will see how to apply this, i ended  doing a frontend pagination.